# Differential equation initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

I have two differential equations:

```
R * (dVi/dt) + (1/C) * Vi + P0 = P1 , 0<=t<=t[i]
R * (dVe/dt) + (1/C) * Ve + P0 = 0 , t[i]<=t<=t[tot]
```

With some help I solved the first one

```
ClearAll[Vi, t, C0, p0, p1, R0];
ode = R0*Vi'[t] + (1/C0)*Vi[t] + p0 == p1
ic = Vi[0] == 0
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, Vi[t], t]
```

But the second one has as initial condition

```
Ve(t[i])=Vi(t[i])
```

I tries to solved it like this knowing that Ve(t[tot])=0 but it doesn't work

```
ode2 = R0*Ve'[t] + (1/C0)*Ve[t] + p0 == 0
ic2 = Ve[t] == Vi[t]
sol2 = NDSolve[{ode2, ic2}, Ve[t], {t, sol, 0}]
```

Comment: Initial conditions can't really be written as `ic2 = Ve[t] == Vi[t]`. You need to give it a specific value at some specific time. may be  `ic2 = Ve[0] == Vi[0]` or something like this. I also do not understand `Ve(t[i])=Vi(t[i])` what is `i` here?

Comment: @Nasser i didn't write it right, I shouldn't write it as t[i] just ti which is a moment in time . I have two intervals, [0,ti] and [ti,ttot]

Comment: Well, when you solve an ODE by hand, the constant of integration is found from initial conditions. So you need to give some specific time value. Something like `Ve[5]==someValue`, Otherwise, I am not sure how giving an interval is going to work. I never seen an ODE solved using interval for initial conditions.

Comment: @Nasser http://cit-evolution.weebly.com/uploads/6/8/9/8/6898684/differential_8e_.pdf   the problem is at page 99 in the pdf, if you have some time to look at it, maybe I don't understant the text enought but I relly don't know how to write it

Comment: @DariusIonut two struggling things: 1.- there is no problem like this one you are asking for help in p. 99 of the book you mention. 2.- how is possible that the second ODE solution will evolve from a time `t[i]` to 0 (`{t, sol ,0}`)?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas it's page 99 pdf or page 80 in the actual book page numeration

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the output of the first ODE at time `ti` as the initial condition for the second ODE.

### ODE #1

```
DSolveValue[
 {
  p0 + vi[t]/c0 + r0 Derivative[1][vi][t] == p1,
  vi[0] == 0
  },
 vi[t],
 t]

(* -c0 E^(-(t/(c0 r0))) (-1 + E^(t/(c0 r0))) (p0 - p1) *)
```

Now we use the answer to define `vi[t]`.

```
vi[t_] := -c0 E^(-(t/(c0 r0))) (-1 + E^(t/(c0 r0))) (p0 - p1)
```

We evaluate it at time `ti` to be used as the initial condition for the second ODE.

```
vi[ti]

(* -c0 E^(-(ti/(c0 r0))) (-1 + E^(ti/(c0 r0))) (p0 - p1) *)
```

### ODE #2

We use the value of `vi[ti]` as the initial condition in the second ODE.

```
DSolveValue[
 {
  p0 + ve[t]/c0 + r0 Derivative[1][ve][t] == 0,
  ve[ti] == -c0 E^(-(ti/(c0 r0))) (-1 + E^(ti/(c0 r0))) (p0 - p1)
  },
 ve[t],
 t]
(* -c0 E^(-(t/(c0 r0))) (-p0 + E^(t/(c0 r0)) p0 + p1 - E^(ti/(c0 r0)) p1) *)
```

and use the answer to define the function `ve[t]`

```
ve[t_] := -c0 E^(-(t/(c0 r0))) (-p0 + E^(t/(c0 r0)) p0 + p1 - E^(ti/(c0 r0)) p1)
```

Now combine the two functions into one (a voltage?).

```
v[t_] := Piecewise[{
   {vi[t], t <= ti}
   },
  ve[t]
  ]
```

Set some values for the parameters and plot the result.

```
r0 = 5;

p0 = 1;

c0 = 1;

p1 = 3;

ti = 1;

Plot[v[t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]